# Nesting ternary operators

Tags: javascript, ternary-operator

I am trying to write a long if else if

```
(!contract.hasOwnProperty('COMMIT_CONTRACT') ? '1') : (contract.hasOwnProperty('COMMIT_CONTRACT') ? '2' : '3')
```

However, this is failing to evaluate.

I started with:

```
(!contract.hasOwnProperty('COMMIT_CONTRACT')) ? '1' : '2')
```

But according to here you can chain them: [javascript shorthand if statement, without the else portion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11554492/javascript-shorthand-if-statement-without-the-else-portion)

But it's not evaluating correctly. What am I doing wrong and how do I fix it?

Comment: () : () is not valid... Also 3 will never be reached.

Comment: Change brackets? `(!contract.hasOwnProperty('COMMIT_CONTRACT')) ? '1' : (contract.hasOwnProperty('COMMIT_CONTRACT') ? '2' : '3')`?

Comment: Your second code is fine. Why do you need the first one  ? a?1:(!a?2:"never reached") makes no sense to me...

Comment: You can only chain them in the sense that if you have `e ? a : b` you can replace `a` or `b` with another `e ? a : b` However, even if the syntax you used were ok, there are only two possible outcomes here.

Comment: contract either has the property or it doesn't, there is no third condition

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> You messed up with parenthesis (`()`).

According to my understanding,
This is your first condition: `!contract.hasOwnProperty('COMMIT_CONTRACT')`,
Your `if` part of first condition is `'1'`,
Your `else` part of first condition is second condition: `contract.hasOwnProperty('COMMIT_CONTRACT')`,
Your `if` part of second condition is `'2'`,
Your `else` part of second condition is `'3'`.

Let's add some parenthesis to make it more readable by us as well to compilers,

```
( !contract.hasOwnProperty('COMMIT_CONTRACT') ) ? '1' : ( contract.hasOwnProperty('COMMIT_CONTRACT') ? '2' : '3' )
```

*Fun Fact, You will never get `'3'`.*

Answer (score 1):

You don't need all the () around everything. This will work just fine:

```
var variable = !contract.hasOwnProperty('COMMIT_CONTRACT') ? '1' : contract.hasOwnProperty('COMMIT_CONTRACT') ? '2' : '3';
```