# How to apply a single line if statement in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, if-statement, material-ui, shorthand

I want to return a class by using a single line if statement like described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11554589/9843082). In my approach I'm using Material-UI and want to set a class.

So I want to use this appraoch `if(condition) expression`

```html
    <Typography className={ if (typeof title === 'string') classes.title } >{ title }</Typography>
```

I get the following error: ***Parsing error: Expression expected***

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2):

You can write it like this:
typeof title === 'string' ? classes.title : ''

Haven't tried it but it should work.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I know this works. But I really want to write it like this: `if(condition) expression`

Comment: Why? The outcome is the same

Comment: I know, but it's more readable in my opinion and I don't have to define an `else` option